# Calling a helper class in Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, helper

I'm trying to create a custom helper module in Magento but I'm getting the following error when I call it from a page :

```
Warning: include(Mage/SEO/Helper/Data.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/strailco/1stclassholidays.com/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

From the template i am using the following to call the helper module:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('SEO')->getFullProductUrl($product); ?>
```

The helper module is set up under:

```
/app/code/local/SEO/Fullurl/Helper/Data.php
/app/code/local/SEO/Fullurl/etc/config.xml
```

Data.php calls the function:

```
<?php 

class getFullProductUrl {

public function getFullProductUrl( $product )
{
}
```

I have my **config.xml** set up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <global>
        <helpers>
        <SEO>
        <class>getFullProductUrl</class>
        </SEO>
        </helpers>
   </global>
</config>
```

I think the problem is the way I have the config.xml set up but I'm struggling to work out the correct way of doing this.

I would be very greatful of any help that you could give. I've been working on this for a couple of days but can't get it working.

Many Thanks

Jason

Comment: I have a similar error with a another modules: ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Adjgiftreg/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in ... where do you call echo Mage::helper('SEO')->getFullProductUrl($product); ??

Answer (score 21):

Your first problem is the config.xml. You have to tell Magento which class you're using.

```
...Other Stuff...
<global>
  ...Other Stuff...
  <helpers>
    <SEO>
      <class>SEO_Fullurl_Helper</class>
    </SEO>
   </helpers>
   ...Other Stuff...
</global>
...Other Stuff...
```

Then you need a Helper in `app/code/local/SEO/Fullurl/Helper/Data.php` that looks like this:

```
class SEO_Fullurl_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

    function getFullProductUrl( $product )
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can do `echo Mage::helper('SEO')->getFullProductUrl($product);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply - in config.xml when you say "other stuff..." what do you mean? Am I missing something from the file?

Comment: You are missing a _lot_ of stuff! Read http://alanstorm.com/magento_config to learn about the configuration files. If you want Blocks, Controllers, or Models you will have to declare them in config.xml also. Read more on http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

Answer (score 1):

I had missed the step of adding the module to app/etc/modules/SEO_Fullurl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SEO_Fullurl>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SEO_Fullurl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I hope this helps someone, very easy mistake to make.